# Max string length or other string limitations from Java Applet to web page?

Tags: java, javascript, string, applet

I'm finding conflicting information on the web about whether any limitations exist on passing large string values (e.g., 100K strings) from a Java applet to its containing web page.

On a related note, is there a max string length for Javascript variables?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested a few strings of length greater than 100K, and encountered no problems.